# How to call JSON data received from the Yahoo Finance API?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

When I use the Yahoo Finance API to retrieve stock quotes from a certain company.

Using the following Javascript code, I was able to retrieve stock data:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(quotes[i], null, 2));
```

I get the following output in my console:

```
{
  "date": "2017-06-06T04:00:00.000Z",
  "open": 153.899994,
  "high": 155.809998,
  "low": 153.779999,
  "close": 154.449997,
  "adjClose": 154.449997,
  "volume": 26624900,
  "symbol": "AAPL"
}
```

So from here, I want to call on only the "close" index from that JSON object. To do this, I tried adding the following in my javascript:

```
  var stockClose = JSON.parse(quotes[i]);
  console.log(stockClose.close);
```

This however does not console log the "close" index of the JSON object. I know this is probably a really dumb mistake I am making and would be grateful if someone could help me debug this. How do I retrieve the "close" index from the quotes object ?

Comment: It seems `quotes[i]` is already an object, so don't call `JSON.parse()`. Try `quotes[i].close`. *"and keeps returning errors"* - What are the specific error messages?

Comment: This worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string.
>
> [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string.

Based on your console log information, we can see it is already a [JSON object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp). So we do not JSON.parse() to parse your quotes[i].

You can either use **quotes[i].close** or **quotes[i]["close"]** to access it.